# Angular 5 BehaviourSubject unsubscribe

Tags: angular

I made a BehaviourSubject inside a service in angular:

```
@Injectable()
export class UsuarioService {
  private _altaUsuarioData: BehaviorSubject<AltaUsuarioProvMunModel>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this._altaUsuarioData = new BehaviorSubject(new AltaUsuarioProvMunModel());
  }

  getAltaUsuarioData() {
     return this._altaUsuarioData.asObservable();
 }
```

I'm accesing it in another component:

```
  this.datosAltaUsuario: Observable<AltaUsuarioProvMunModel>;

  constructor(){
  this.datosAltaUsuario = this.usuarioService.getAltaUsuarioData();
    this.datosAltaUsuario.subscribe(
      resp => {
            ...
```

- How can I unsubscribe from the BehaviourSubject?.
- Does onDestroy takes care of it?.
- Am I doing good creating the instance with asObservable() and creating the observable "this.datosAltaUsuario: Observable;"?
- I'm a bit worried about possible memory leaks

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. `this['subscription'] = this.datosAltaUsuario.subscribe();`, then `this['subscription'].unsubscribe();`
2. You can do it in `ngOnDestroy`, but it doesn't do it implicitly : **you have to write the unsbuscribe**.
3. I don't know about the best practice, but it's definitely not the worst practice.
4. If you unsubscribe you don't have to worry.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer. 
If I  try this.datosAltaUsuario.unsubscribe(); it returns me [ts] property "unsubscribe" does not exist for the type "Observable<AltaUsuarioProvMunModel>". What to do?

Comment: I don't know how it is possible. Where do you call this unsubscribe function  ?

Comment: Inside the component I can't use any kind of unsub with the observable "this.datosAltaUsuario". 
That's why I'm wondering if It destroys whenever the component is destroyed or not

Comment: Oh god how dumb I am. Please look at the edit of my answer, on the first point.